# How to wrap a tag around a tag in a string - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a String. Say it looks like this:

```
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html&gt;
    &lt;head&gt;
        &lt;title&gt;Web Page&lt;/title&gt;
    &lt;/head&gt;
    &lt;body&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;Content.&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
```

How do I make it so that the output looks like this?

```
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;<span class="tag>html</span>&gt;
    &lt;<span class="tag>head</span>&gt;
        &lt;<span class="tag>title</span>&gt;Web Page&lt;<span class="tag>/title</span>&gt;
    &lt;<span class="tag>/head</span>&gt;
    &lt;<span class="tag>body</span>&gt;
        &lt;<span class="tag>p</span>&gt;Content.&lt;<span class="tag>/p</span>&gt;
    &lt;<span class="tag>/body</span>&gt;
&lt;<span class="tag>/html</span>&gt;
```

Comment: I am doing it on purpose

Comment: I'm assuming he or she is trying to include a formatted code snippet of some sort. You'll have to be more descriptive of what you want. I can see both snippets you've provided but nobody wants to sit and play spot-the-difference to figure out what you're trying to achieve. Give us a short explanation of what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am trying to post a formatted code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to replace all tags with wrapped span.

```
str.replace(/&lt;(\/?\w+)&gt;/g, '&lt;<span class="tag">$1</span>&gt;');
// or .replace(/(&lt;)(\/?\w+)(&gt;)/g, '$1<span class="tag">$2</span>$3')
```

```js
var str = `&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html&gt;
    &lt;head&gt;
        &lt;title&gt;Web Page&lt;/title&gt;
    &lt;/head&gt;
    &lt;body&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;Content.&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;`

document.body.innerHTML = str.replace(/&lt;(\/?\w+)&gt;/g, '&lt;<span class="tag">$1</span>&gt;');
```

```css
.tag {
  color: red;
}
```

---

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/QvIs0r/1)

Comment: @Rishi :  glad to help :)

Answer (score -1):

I would do this in two steps, using `String.replace`...

```
str.replace(/&lt;/g,'&lt;<span class="tag">').replace(/&gt;/g,'</span>&gt;');
```